# Importing Files with nuxt.js (Vue equivalent of getElementById())

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm having trouble loading a file in one of my components. It worked before I moved to Vue using getElementById(). Here is what I have tried:
In template:

```
<input type="file" accept=".obj" id="file" ref="OBJImport" name="objFile" @change="loadFileAsText()" single />
```

In data:

```
data(){
    return {
         files: []
    }
}
```

In methods:

```
methods: {  
    loadFileAsText: function() {
        if(process.client) {
            this.files = this.$refs.OBJImport.files[0];
            console.log(files);
         }
    }
```

But when I try to upload the file, I get:

```
ReferenceError: files is not defined
```

I have also tried without the `[0]`. Changing `.files[0]` to `.file` still yields the same error for `files`. What should I do to get my file from the template to my methods? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `()` from the change event:

```
<input type="file" accept=".obj" id="file" ref="OBJImport" name="objFile" @change="loadFileAsText" single />
```

Use the default event parameter

```
methods: {  
  loadFileAsText: function(e) {
    if(process.client) {
      //this.files = this.$refs.OBJImport.files[0];
      //console.log(files); // Here is this.files, not files, this is your initial error.
      this.files = e.target.files[0];
      console.log(this.files);
  }
}
```

The `files` you log does not exist, this is your only error.
In addition, I have provided another way to get files.

Comment: Worked perfectly and great explanation. Thank you!